# Is there a way to write 'good' queries against the SQL-CSV-Antipattern?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

TL;DR at the bottom.

I have inherited a rather poorly-designed table which holds a log of requests against a third-party webservice. This table contains a timestamp, two fields named metadata_1 and metadata_2 which allow you to identify the user, and a very long VARCHAR2 field named TEXT.

This TEXT field holds the actual request information, represented as a comma-separated list of values. Somewhere buried in this list are two relevant bits of information, which I'll call "request type" and "request key." I am trying to figure out, for each user, the ratio of unsuccessful requests to total requests per day and request key. This value is then to be compared against the global error rate for that day, to identify devices that have trouble talking to the webservice. (The metadata only identifies the user, so getting to their devices involves a little additional effort.) A non-successful request has a field I'll call "error type" which is inserted before the request type.

As you probably guessed from that last sentence, the format of this comma-separated list of values is not consistent. In particular, the position of the KEY field in the comma-separated list depends on the request type, whose position in turn depends on whether the request was successful. All of these fields are variable-length.

So a TEXT field could look like this:

```
"2017-04-05T07:21:00.569Z,html_error:403,get_status,80,asdf2k,1,0,KEY_123,hunter2"

"2017-04-05T07:21:01.529Z,html_error:403,get_status,80,asdf2k,1,0,KEY_123,hunter2"
```

But it could also look like this:

```
"2017-04-05T07:23:46.459Z,send_events,80,qwert-8,2,1,KEY_123,foobar,1,1,false,114,11838"
```

My question is: How would you tackle this problem? There is a query that works in the test environment, reproduced below, but its performance is extremely poor. There has got to be a better way to do this. Assume that this all has to be done in a single query and that I have no influence on either the environment or the database design. (Note that there's some additional filtering going on here. Anything else that seems odd is likely an error I made during the anonymization. This is more about the strategy I'm using - I'm not asking you to write the query for me.)

---

Desired result: For each user, day and request key, the number of successful and unsuccessful requests, compared to the ratio of successful requests for that day.

Current result: As described, but with unacceptable performance.

```
select a.*, b.success_rate_day from (select device.serial_id, rql.date, rql.KEY, rql.requests_ok, rql.requests_error
from device, user, 
    (select request_log.meta_1, request_log.meta_2, to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD') AS date,
        (select count(b.TEXT) 
            FROM request_log b 
            where b.meta_1 = request_log.meta_1 
            and b.meta_2 = request_log.meta_2 
            and b.text NOT LIKE '%error%' 
            and to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD') = to_char(b.created_timestamp, 'DDD') 
            and (CASE 
                    WHEN b.TEXT LIKE '%html_error%' THEN SUBSTR(b.TEXT, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)+1, (INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 1)-INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)-1)) 
                    WHEN b.TEXT LIKE '%get_status%' THEN SUBSTR(b.TEXT, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)+1, (INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 3)-INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)-1)) 
                    WHEN b.TEXT LIKE '%send_events%' THEN SUBSTR(b.TEXT, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)+1, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', 1, 7)-INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)-1) 
                    ELSE 'Error' 
                END) = (CASE 
                    WHEN request_log.TEXT LIKE '%html_error%' THEN SUBSTR(request_log.TEXT, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)+1, (INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 1)-INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)-1)) 
                    WHEN request_log.TEXT LIKE '%get_status%' THEN SUBSTR(request_log.TEXT, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)+1, (INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 3)-INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)-1)) 
                    WHEN request_log.TEXT LIKE '%send_events%' THEN SUBSTR(request_log.TEXT, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)+1, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', 1, 7)-INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)-1) 
                    ELSE 'Error' 
                END)
        ) AS requests_ok, 
        (select count(b.TEXT) 
            FROM request_log b 
            where b.meta_1 = request_log.meta_1 
            and b.meta_2 = request_log.meta_2 
            and b.text LIKE '%error%' 
            and to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD') = to_char(b.created_timestamp, 'DDD') 
            and (CASE 
                    WHEN b.TEXT LIKE '%html_error%' THEN SUBSTR(b.TEXT, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)+1, (INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 1)-INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)-1)) 
                    WHEN b.TEXT LIKE '%get_status%' THEN SUBSTR(b.TEXT, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)+1, (INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 3)-INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)-1)) 
                    WHEN b.TEXT LIKE '%send_events%' THEN SUBSTR(b.TEXT, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)+1, INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', 1, 7)-INSTR(b.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)-1) 
                    ELSE 'Error' 
                END) = (CASE 
                    WHEN request_log.TEXT LIKE '%html_error%' THEN SUBSTR(request_log.TEXT, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)+1, (INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 1)-INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 2)-1)) 
                    WHEN request_log.TEXT LIKE '%get_status%' THEN SUBSTR(request_log.TEXT, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)+1, (INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 3)-INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', -1, 4)-1)) 
                    WHEN request_log.TEXT LIKE '%send_events%' THEN SUBSTR(request_log.TEXT, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)+1, INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', 1, 7)-INSTR(request_log.TEXT, ';', 1, 6)-1) 
                    ELSE 'Error' 
                END)
        ) AS requests_error,
        (CASE 
            WHEN TEXT LIKE '%html_error%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 2)+1, (INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 1)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 2)-1)) 
            WHEN TEXT LIKE '%get_status%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 4)+1, (INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 3)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 4)-1)) 
            WHEN TEXT LIKE '%send_events%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 6)+1, INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 7)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 6)-1) 
            ELSE 'Error' 
        END) AS KEY
    from request_log 
    where request_log.meta_1 <= 99999
    and extract(hour from request_log.created_timestamp) BETWEEN 5 AND 23 
    group by request_log.meta_1, 
            request_log.meta_2,
            to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD'), 
            (CASE 
                    WHEN TEXT LIKE '%html_error%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 2)+1, (INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 1)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 2)-1)) 
                    WHEN TEXT LIKE '%get_status%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 4)+1, (INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 3)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 4)-1)) 
                    WHEN TEXT LIKE '%send_events%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 6)+1, INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 7)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 6)-1) 
                    ELSE 'Error' 
            END)
    ) rql
where (device.user_ID = user.id)
and (user.meta_1 = rql.meta_1)
and (user.meta_2 = rql.meta_2)) a,
    (select rql_global.date, rql_global.success_rate_day
from (select to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD') AS date, ROUND(
        (select count(b.TEXT) FROM request_log b where b.meta_1 <= 99999 and extract(hour from b.created_timestamp) BETWEEN 5 AND 23 and b.text NOT LIKE '%error%' and to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD') = to_char(b.created_timestamp, 'DDD'))
        /
        GREATEST((select count(c.TEXT) FROM request_log c where c.meta_1 <= 99999 and extract(hour from c.created_timestamp) BETWEEN 5 AND 23 and to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD') = to_char(c.created_timestamp, 'DDD')), 1), 4) *100
    AS success_rate_day
    from request_log 
    group by to_char(request_log.created_timestamp, 'DDD')
    ) rql_global) b
where a.date = b.date
order by serial_id ASC, a.date ASC, KEY ASC;
```

Comment: Is there a chance to define an m-view on this table, with the CSV column parsed and split into the fields you care about? Parsing it once on insert is likely cheaper than parsing it in every query.

Comment: I agree with @9000 above: I would add the two relevant fields as new distinct field, split and populate everything (while the DB is offline) and also add a trigger on Insert to automatically populate the new field in the future (this way you do not have to touch anything else and still move forward)

Comment: I like the idea of a materialized view. Getting a change on this database isn't easy, but if there's no other option, I might have to resort to that.

Comment: Is `TEXT` really a VARCHAR2 column or is it a CLOB?

Comment: VARCHAR2, I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be rewritten as follows:

```
WITH log_info AS (SELECT meta_1,
                         meta_2,
                         to_char(created_timestamp, 'DDD') dt,
                         CASE 
                           WHEN TEXT LIKE '%html_error%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 2)+1, (INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 1)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 2)-1)) 
                           WHEN TEXT LIKE '%get_status%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 4)+1, (INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 3)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', -1, 4)-1)) 
                           WHEN TEXT LIKE '%send_events%' THEN SUBSTR(TEXT, INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 6)+1, INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 7)-INSTR(TEXT, ';', 1, 6)-1) 
                           ELSE 'Error' 
                         END key_val
                  FROM   request_log 
                  where  request_log.meta_1 <= 99999
                  and    extract(hour from request_log.created_timestamp) BETWEEN 5 AND 23),
           li AS (SELECT meta_1,
                         meta_2,
                         dt,
                         key_val,
                         COUNT(CASE WHEN text NOT LIKE '%error%' THEN 1 END) requests_ok,
                         COUNT(CASE WHEN text LIKE '%error%' THEN 1 END) requests_error,
                         COUNT(*) total_requests
                  FROM   log_info
                  GROUP BY meta_1,
                           meta_2,
                           dt,
                           key_val),
           rl AS (SELECT meta_1,
                         meta_2,
                         dt,
                         key_val,
                         requests_ok,
                         requests_error,
                         SUM(requests_error) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) requests_error_by_ddd,
                         SUM(total_requests) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) total_requests_by_ddd
                  FROM   li)
SELECT d.serial_id,
       rql.date,
       rql.key,
       rql.requests_ok,
       rql.requests_error,
       ROUND(100 * reqests_error_by_ddd/greatest(total_requests_by_ddd, 1), 2) success_rate_day
FROM   device d
       INNER JOIN usr u ON d.user_id = u.id
       INNER JOIN rl ON u.meta_1 = rl.meta_1
                        AND u.meta_2 = rl.meta_2;
```

You'll have to check that I've managed to get the logic correct, though.

First off, you're repeating the key's case statement all over the place, so I pulled that out into a separate subquery (`log_info`).

Next, it looked like you wanted to do a conditional count, so rather than using a separate scalar subquery to get the counts, I got the counts using case to restrict the rows I wanted to count (null values don't get included in the count). This is done in the `li` subquery.

Then, it seemed like you needed to get the total requests and total error requests per day, so I used an analytic sum() function to pull that information together for all rows on the same day - that's done in the `rl` subquery.

Then, in the final query, I do the joins to the other tables plus the success_rate_day calculation. Note that I converted the joins from the old-style syntax into ANSI join syntax.

Assuming I do have your logic correct, this ought to be a lot more performant than your current query. If I've got the logic wrong, hopefully you'll be able to amend my query accordingly.

I also add my voice to the chorus suggesting the table be optimised, pulling the info out into their own separate columns *{;-)

Comment: Took a little bit of tinkering (stray comma in front of a FROM, measuring the error rate rather than the success rate), but very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Apologies for the typo; I've removed the extra comma from my answer! I'm glad you were able amend the query for your purposes - I suspect I misread the "NOT LIKE" as "LIKE", hence me picking the wrong thing to measure! I hope it made enough sense to you that you can generate simpler queries against your tables in the future?

Comment: Indeed, it was very helpful. I still have much to learn about subquery usage, I suppose. (And WITH-AS for that matter.)